# Django form field dynmaic attr

Tags: python, django, forms

How do I set the the attributes dynamicallyfor a form field in a Django form? 
Right now I can use the follwing for a fixed attribute.

```
time_record = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
```

Let's say I want to dynamically to add a attribute called "data-record" during the form instantiation, how would I do that?

Comment: You can add the `data-record` to the form and leave it empty. Then you can can always add the value with JavaScript or your Django form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the attrs dictionary of the widget of the field:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.fields['time_record'].widget.attrs['data-record'] = ''
```